# How to fix Index Error when trying to match catalogs using astropy coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, matching, catalog, astropy

I’m trying to match catalog sources using the astropy coordinates package, and I have three different files of data.  My ultimate goal is for all three files to contain data for the same exact sources.

I thought I had figured it out because when I compare the files `F435W.csv` and `F550M.csv`, the code seems to work and both end up with the same number of sources, just like I wanted.  When I use the same exact code to compare my third file `F625W.csv` to `F435W.csv`, I get an `IndexError: index 6442 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6348`. Why would I be getting this error with one file but not the other?

There is a significant difference between the number of sources between all three files, which is what I think would normally cause this error, but it doesn't make sense why it would work with the first two files with different array lengths but not with third file with a different array length from the first two.

```
import numpy as np

my_csv1 = np.genfromtxt('./F435W.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
ra1, dec1 = my_csv1[:, 12], my_csv1[:, 13]
my_csv2 = np.genfromtxt('./F625W.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
ra2, dec2 = my_csv2[:, 12], my_csv2[:, 13]

from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import match_coordinates_sky

c = SkyCoord(ra1, dec1, frame='icrs', unit='deg')
catalog = SkyCoord(ra2, dec2, frame='icrs', unit='deg')

max_sep = 2.0*u.arcsec
idx, sep, _ = c.match_to_catalog_sky(catalog)
sep_constraint = idx[sep < max_sep]
c_matches = c[sep_constraint]
catalog_matches = c[idx[sep_constraint]]

print (len(c_matches), len(catalog_matches))
```

When using `F435W.csv` and `F550M.csv` my code outputs array lengths `4703 4703`, so they are the same length, same number of sources.  When I change `F550M.csv` to `F625.csv` I get the `IndexError`.  According to the error information, it seems to be coming from line 19 `c_matches = c[sep_constraint]`

Comment: I don't know anything about numpy, and haven't looked closely at your code.  I figure this isn't the problem either, but something jumps out to me as strange...this line: **sep_constraint = idx[sep < max_sep]**.  Isn't this indexing the **idx** list by a boolean value?  Is that really what you want/mean?  Just curious more than anything

Comment: @Steve Without knowing more about what `sep_constraint` and `sep` are, it's hard to say, but that could be valid code - indexing a `numpy` array using a boolean mask.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, mainly because when I looked at the documentation for matching coordinates with astropy, it stated to do this when needing to use a maximum separation for coordinates to be considered a match.  That's what I used as a guide for my code. It stated something like this and gave an example similar to the code I used: "It is possible to impose a separation constraint (e.g., the maximum separation to be considered a match) by creating a boolean mask...."

Comment: Cool guys.  As I said, I was just curious.  I do realize that it is up to the underlying object to define the possible index types, so all good!  Thanks for the education.  One of these days, I may actually use numpy. - a colleague of mine uses it constantly.  It seems sometimes that numpy and pandas are taking over the Python world, lol.

Comment: Are you on Linux? If that is the case, what is the output of ```wc -l``` for each file?

Comment: I'm not on Linux.  What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Please one question per actual question. Since it's a broader question you might consider asking it in a more astronomy-focused forum such as the Astropy mailing list.

Comment: In the code you posted as is you just print `len(c_matches)` and `len(catalog_matches)`. But that's not telling you anything a out the sizez  of the original arrays, which you might want to look at. And `IndexError` just, as the message suggests, indicates that you're trying to index an array with an index that's outside the array's bounds. If the two pairs of ra/dec columns have different lengths then you have to account for the ranges where they don't overlap.

Comment: I already knew the lengths of the arrays are different, but I was confused because it works with F435 and F550 which have different array lengths but not with F435 and F625 which also have different array lengths.  My confusion is why it would work with one file but not the other even though they should all have different lengths.  Since I'm pretty sure that is the issue,  I have no clue how I would account for that sort of issue.  I've looked at other questions with a similar issue, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply that to what I am doing.

Comment: @Sam You won't get an error if say, the length of the array of F550 is greater than F435 because the index is still within bounds. In the case of F435 and F625, I suppose F625 is the smaller array and therefore, the error is thrown. If this is the way to proceed with these files, I think you can try filling up the smaller array with np.Nan or None to match the length of F435

Comment: @kerwei F625 is the larger array. It has length 10829 while F435 has length 6348.  F550 has length 6349, so those two are actually very close in length.  If I switch F435 to the second array it doesn't give me the error but then it doesn't accomplish my goal since I'm trying to match to F435 specifically because it has the least number of sources.

Comment: @Sam That's the size of the array in the source files or after the SkyCoord transformation?

Comment: @kerwei In the source files before the transformation.

Comment: @Sam SkyCoord would've probably truncated the length of that array due to invalid inputs etc. As stated in the error message, the length of the array has been shortened to 6k++. I have no idea how you match the 2 arrays together (by coords or whatever else) but one way to sidestep this error is to patch the shorter array by filling it up with np.Nan so that you have 2 arrays of equal length

Comment: @kerwei Oh okay.  I see what you mean.  I can try that.